# Add ICollection list of User to Existing Roles List in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, icollection

I have User and Role classes, each with List define. Now I want to add list of users to specific role, in other word I want to put List of user reference in ICollection Role.

### User

```
 public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public  bool ActiveStatus { get; set; }

     public List<User> Users = new List<User>();

  public List<User> BuildUserRepository()
    {
        Users.Add(new User { UserID = 01, Name = "Khurram", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = true });
        Users.Add(new User { UserID = 02, Name = "Sana", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = true });
        Users.Add(new User { UserID = 03, Name = "Richard", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = false });
        Users.Add(new User { UserID = 04, Name = "Tracy", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = true });
        Users.Add(new User { UserID = 05, Name = "Laura", Address = "Manchester", ActiveStatus = true });
        Users.Add(new User { UserID = 06, Name = "James", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = false });

        return Users;
    }
}
```

### Role

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string RoleTitle { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> UsersInRole { get; set; }

    public List<Role> Roles = new List<Role>();

    public void BuildRoleRepository()
    {
        Roles.Add(new Role { RoleID = 01, RoleTitle = "Admin" });
        Roles.Add(new Role { RoleID = 02, RoleTitle = "Management" });
        Roles.Add(new Role { RoleID = 03, RoleTitle = "User" });
    }
 }
```

now I want to add for example two user of UserID 01 and 02 to Role ICollection where RoleID = 01, how can I do this

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem or not, but based on the code you posted each instance of `User` will have its own user list, and each instance of `Role` will have its own role list. This probably isn't what you want. You might want to create a separate class that has the global list of users and roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some drastic changes to the design of your solution, you can accomplish it by the following code snippet below. But remember that [hard coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) of the actual/testing data inside your classes is usually introducing a lot of limitations further on and is often considered an anti-pattern. You might be better off using external data storage (file or database) and [Repository Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) as your persistence layer. Hope it helps!

```
Role.Roles.First(x => x.RoleID == 01)
    .UsersInRole.AddRange(
        User.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == 01 || x.UserID == 02));

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool ActiveStatus { get; set; }

    public static List<User> Users = new List<User>
    {
        new User {UserID = 01, Name = "Khurram", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = true},
        new User {UserID = 02, Name = "Sana", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = true},
        new User {UserID = 03, Name = "Richard", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = false},
        new User {UserID = 04, Name = "Tracy", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = true},
        new User {UserID = 05, Name = "Laura", Address = "Manchester", ActiveStatus = true},
        new User {UserID = 06, Name = "James", Address = "London", ActiveStatus = false}
    };
}

public class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string RoleTitle { get; set; }
    public List<User> UsersInRole { get; set; }

    public static List<Role> Roles = new List<Role>
    {
        new Role {RoleID = 01, RoleTitle = "Admin"},
        new Role {RoleID = 02, RoleTitle = "Management"},
        new Role {RoleID = 03, RoleTitle = "User"}
    };
}
```

Comment: I am well aware, this is only for testing purposes. I normally use database base with repository pattern